# How to get the value of a static object from within that object?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, memory, static

I’m trying to create a extern pointer to the value of a static object from within that static object. We’ll call this object Foo.

Thus far, the only way I’ve gotten this to work is to create a Supervisor class that Foo inherits from that contains two static type variables. One, called superObject is the actual initialized object. The other, called superPointer, is a double pointer of the same type. Inside of the Foo object I declare an extern pointer named TheSupervisor and assign it a nullptr. Then, from within the Supervisor base class, I use the double pointer superPointer to change the value of TheSupervisor extern pointer to the address of the superObject. Wallah.

The goal is here to create a globally accessible reference to this object. Trying my best to avoid singletons and keep things thread safe. I’m just wondering if there’s a better way?

I'd post code, but I'd really have to clean it and change it around. I think the description is sufficient. Maybe even simpler, actually.

EDIT: As it turns out, for static objects, I can't rely on when and in what order they are constructed. Using a one-phase process won't work for this. Instead, I have to keep relying on a two-phase process such as the one I outlined above. Marking 
Ilya Kobelevskiy's answer as correct as it demonstrates one way to do it, but again, it should come with a warning when used with static objects.

Comment: Good question. This Foo class is actually a templated class. For this particular type of Foo I'm using template specialization to initialize it and then create global access to it as outlined above. I only want one of these. For the other types, however, these things don't happen and I could have more than one of them. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but won't

```
class Foo
{
//some methods
public:
Foo* getSelf() const { return this;}
}
```

just work?

Comment: Marking as the answer, but see my EDIT above about its use with static objects.

Comment: @Stradigos I think you are over-thinking it. Note that the method getSelf() is *non-static*. Therefore, there is no need to make any assumptions on objects creation order - method can only be called from existing object after object have been created, and it will return a pointer to that object - is object static or not doesn't matter in this contest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand what you said in the comment above, but I'm uncertain if this is what you're looking for or not.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        static Foo* shared_instance() {return &shared_instance_;};

    private:
        static Foo shared_instance_;
}
```

This way you can either use the shared instance as is, or instantiate new ones when, and if, needed.